# Error when running a test with hyperledger caliper

Tags: docker, caliper, hyperledger-caliper

I have been trying for days to run a test with 3 Organizations that having 3 peers each. The tutorial that i am trying to make it work: https://github.com/haojun/caliper
This is my first time, working with hyperledger.

Docker: 19.03.8

Node: 8.17.0

node-gyp: 3.0.03

Docker-compose: 1.24.1

Ubuntu: 16.04

When i place the command

```
node benchmark/simple/main.js -c config.json -n composer-tls.json
```

the result that i get is:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARDaN.png)